# jquery ui resizable custom method, check box to toggle ratio on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery ui to make a div resizable but I would like to implement a check box that toggles the ratio between off and 16/9.

is this possible? can I add custom methods to resizable? 
I have checked out some other questions but non of them were able to help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/zkzgpndz/3/

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Preserve aspect ratio</h3>
</div>
```

```
var ratio;

$('#ratio').click( function() {
    var ischecked = $('#ratio').is(":checked")

    if (ischecked) {
        ratio = " "
    } else {
        ratio = "16 /9"
    }
});


$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        aspectRatio: ratio
    });
});
```

Comment: The system wants you to include relevant code in your question in addition to the fiddle link.  Please do so and you will be able to post the link directly instead of working around the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to destroy and reinitiate the `resizable` to enforce the `aspectRatio` option.

```
$('#ratio').click( function() {
    if($('#ratio').is(":checked"))
        ratio = 16/9;
    else
        ratio = false;
    $("#resizable").resizable('destroy').resizable({
        aspectRatio: ratio
    });
});
$("#resizable").resizable();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zkzgpndz/4/